# Responsive design support of phone gap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

So I have an app I made using phone gap as a wrapper and targeted at specifically iPad. Now I want to incorporate an iPhone version of the app but have it so that its all complied together in one app. So I guess what my question is, does phone gap allow for device specific layouts and let you use JavaScript to detect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but the fastest way is probably to get the screen size of the device and start from there:

```
var widthScreen = window.innerWidth;
var heightScreen = window.innerHeight;
```

According to the size you get you can safely assume if you're working on iPads vs. iPhone5 vs. iPhone4 and make your changes.