# Responsive Images in Phonegap

Tags: php, image, cordova, responsive-design

I want to have responsive images in my Phonegap app however how can this done with the images coming from a mysql database and php as the server side.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to apply some CSS to said images in order for them to become responsive, it does not matter if the images are loaded from an `img` `src`'s or a mysql database.

Try this CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 1000px;  //upper-bound
    min-width: 320px;  //lower-bound
    width: 100%;  //set the image to be the width of whatever the screen width is now
}
```

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179999/responsive-design-support-of-phone-gap) which covers the best way to handle responsive design within PhoneGap - you can use the built-in methods for calling the device string, however the __most effective way__ is to use media queries and max- & min-width.